# How to go about re-fixing a badly done patch in the basement concrete floor?

Tags: basement, flooring, cement

[image]Just got this house, and shortly after noticed a room in the basement had damp carpet. Pulled it up, sprinkler system had leaked into the room and the carpet was soaked, carpet had clearly been thrown over damaged vinyl tiles from the last time they had the same problem. Tiles were crumbling so pulled them out too.

In one corner I find this really badly done patch to the concrete.

Is there anything special about how I should go about patching this compared to how one might patch concrete outdoors?

I have seen posts where people try to remove as much as possible of the badly patched/loose stuff then pour new concrete to patch, but not in much detail.

Comment: What are your plans for the area?  The answer will determine how  intensive the repair need to be.  For example, if you are carpeting, it is fine as it is.

Comment: I prefer to not do carpeting in the basement, but that sounds like good news that if I was, it would be fine as is. I haven't settled on any specific flooring but leaning towards LVP or cork, rather than tile or hardwood.

Comment: HIghly dependant on what flooring you intend to put down but putting some self-leveling cement in the corner area should fill in and even out the concrete enough for most kind of flooring. OTOH you _could_ remove the old patch and re-patch it, but the end result is likely to be about the same when it's all said and done.

Comment: Is water coming through the concrete

Answer (score 1):

First take a masonry chisel and knock the big parts off the top.  Remember you are not chiseling down into the concrete, but across the top.

An old trick from my father -in-law, was to take a brick or concrete block and slide it over the concrete back and forth.  It's a great work out and surprisingly smooths out the patch.

If you get the floor smooth enough you are done for most LVP or laminate floors.

Should there be deep pockets or a very rough surface left, smooth it over with leveling compound, or thin set mortar.

Since it's a basement, use a vapor barrier [underlayment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HDN4SDQ)
 that has just a little padding to smooth over any slightly rough parts

Comment: Maybe some self-leveling compound after knocking off any high spots?